# Using `pkg-config` as command line argument under cygwin/msys bash

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, makefile, pkg-config

I'm trying to use cygwin as a build environment under Windows. I have some dependencies on 3rd party packages, for example, GTK+.

Normally when I build under Linux, in my Makefile I can add a call to pkg-config as an argument to gcc, so it comes out like so:

```
gcc example.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

This works fine under Linux, but in cygwin I get:

```
:Invalid argument
make: *** [example] Error 1
```

Right now, I am just manually running pkg-config and pasting the output into the Makefile, which is truly terrible. Is there a good way to workaround or fix for this issue?

Make isn't the culprit. I can copy and paste the command line that make uses to call gcc, and that by itself will run gcc, which halts with ": Invalid argument".

I wrote a small test program to print out command line arguments:

```
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    printf("'%s'\n", argv[i]);
```

Notice the single quotes.

```
$ pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0
-Lc:/mingw/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpang
owin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-
2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Running through the test program:

```
$ ./t `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
'C:\cygwin\home\smo\pvm\src\t.exe'
'-Lc:/mingw/lib'
'-lgtk-win32-2.0'
'-lgdk-win32-2.0'
'-latk-1.0'
'-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0'
'-lpangowin32-1.0'
'-lgdi32'
'-lpangocairo-1.0'
'-lpango-1.0'
'-lcairo'
'-lgobject-2.0'
'-lgmodule-2.0'
'-lglib-2.0'
'-lintl'
'
```

Notice the one single quote on the last line. It looks like argc is one greater than it should be, and argv[argc - 1] is null. Running the same test on Linux does not have this result.

That said, is there, say, some way I could have the Makefile store the result of pkg-config into a variable, and then use that variable, rather than using the back-tick operator?

Comment: Iam also on a Win 64-System (Vista64) and struggling at the same point.
I have noticed thadt 32 and 64-Bit GTK Installations confuses pkg-config and
the lib path are not correctly determined. Iam now looking for a non pkg-config Solution, so i can better understand what is exactly happend on the linker process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> That said, is there, say, some way I could have the Makefile store the result of pkg-config into a variable, and then use that variable, rather than using the back-tick operator?

GTK_LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0)

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you're using the make provided by Cygwin? Use

```
which make
make --version
```

to check - this should return "/usr/bin/make" and "GNU Make 3.8 [...]" or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... have you tried

```
make -d
```

That will give you some (lots) of debugging output.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it is definitely running gcc, but gcc is having the problem. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that cygwin's gcc can't handle -Lc:/mingw/lib.  Try translating that to a cygwin path.

```
GTK_LIBS = $(patsubst -Lc:/%,-L/cygdrive/c/%,$(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0))
```

Comment: Nah, it's actually mingw gcc -- I neglected to mention this.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been nice to know :).  Mingw gcc seems to be fine with C:/ paths.

Answer (score 1):

The single quote at the end of the "t" output may be an artifact of CRLF translation.  Is your pkg-config a cygwin app?  The $(shell) solution I posted earlier may help with this, as GNU make seems to be fairly tolerant of different line ending styles.

Comment: I agree it is probably related to crlf.

The pkg-config is actually from mingw, as well. I had tried dropping in the cygwin pkg-config but that was using the cygwin paths which mingw didn't like, but I did confirm that the cygwin pkg-config does not create an extra null argv.

Comment: Interesting... I don't have a pkg-config in my mingw installation to test.  Must have been an optional package (I have the gcc 3.4.5 mingw).

Comment: I think I tracked down the pkg-config as coming from the GTK+ bundle:
http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I found a fix here: http://www.demexp.org/dokuwiki/en:demexp_build_on_windows

> Take care to put /usr/bin before /cygwin/c/GTK/bin in your PATH so that you use /usr/bin/pkg-config. This is required because GTK's pkg-config post-processes paths, often transforming them in their Windows absolute paths equivalents. As a consequence, tools under cygwin may not understand those paths.